# MySQL Query - Search using wildcards at front and rear and an input parameter. Visual Studio 2012 - VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, tableadapter

I am currently working on a POS system as a project for my studies. We are building the application in VB winforms using visual studio 2012.

I have the MySQL for Visual Studio installed and have a datasource/connection/dataset set up via the data sources panel in VS.

I am currently trying to make a TableAdapter query using the VS Query Builder which searches a product name however using  the standard WHERE (ProductName = @inputParamName) you need a 100% match in @inputParamName for it to display the respective data.

I have tried using WHERE (ProductName LIKE '%' + @inputParamName + '%') however it gives me a MySQL error.

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I edited my answer to use a different approach.  You can do the following.  When you create a SqlDataSource in VS, it adds the SelectCommand in the aspx.  Set the command to nothing and add a SelectParameter, like this:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="param1" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now in the code behind, you can change the SelectCommand and pass it a param like this:

```
         {
        // Run this on a click or selected index change
        string m_param = "2012";  //this would be something like Textbox1.Text

        this.SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = m_param;
        this.SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT ID, FILENAME FROM drmc.checksum WHERE FILENAME LIKE '%" + this.SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue + "%'";

         }
```

You will need to test the "Textbox1.Text" value against SQL Injection.  Regex is good for this.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately my experience with MySQL is rather limited. Therefore the stored procedure route seems a little complex. I would have preferred to use T-SQL / MSSQL as I have more experience with this however my group only has a MySQL server at our disposal. Can you elaborate more on the escaping using \ please? 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your revised answer. I still haven't got it sorted but this method looks much easier and I will implement it when i revisit the search function.